Gunicorn Error: ModuleNotFoundError - No module named 'weatherapp.wsgi'
I'm having some trouble deploying my Django application on Heroku using Gunicorn, and I could really use some assistance.
Here's some background information about my project:
Project Name: weatherapp
Procfile
web: gunicorn weatherapp.wsgi:application --log-file -
wsgi.py
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'weatherapp.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()

Error Message

Traceback (most recent call last): File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 609, in spawn_worker ... ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'weatherapp.wsgi'

Relevant code in settings.py
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'content_aggregator.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
django_heroku.settings(locals())

MEDIA_URL = '/imgs/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'imgs'

It seems like Gunicorn is unable to locate the weatherapp.wsgi module during the deployment process.
I've double-checked my project structure and everything seems to be in order. Could anyone please provide some guidance on what might be causing this issue and how I can resolve it?
Started the Gunicorn server with the command gunicorn weatherapp.wsgi:application --log-file -.
But no changes

maybe you needs wsgi.py instead of weatherapp.wsgi in gunicorn wsgi:application. OR maybe you have to add to sys.path folder in which you have folder weatherapp

"I've double-checked my project structure and everything seems to be in order"—please show us your project structure including the location of your .git/ directory (this is your root directory) as well as the relative path to your wsgi.py file.

The reason might be that unlike in dev mode your terminal does not sit within the folder of your project. I can't explain it well, but that procfile might try to start the app from within your home directory - but there is no weatherapp in it!
You could test this with creating a print_cwd.py:
import os
print("Current working directory:", os.getcwd())

and then within your procfile:
web: python /full/path/to/print_cwd.py

Give the full path here, otherwise it won't find the print_cwd.py file either.
To make your gunicorn run you can also just pass the full path!
procfile
web: gunicorn /full/path/to/weatherapp.wsgi:application --log-file -


This isn't a great solution on Heroku since they can choose to move where your application lives in the filesystem. That would cause the app to break. They've done this in the past. The relative path within the project directly should be used instead.
